# nickperkinslondon angular treeview expand_all() problems

Tags: javascript, angular, treeview

I'm using this angular treeview project:

https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree

I think that this treeview haven't got functions to do searches over treeview, so I implemented mine using a form to write the label to find.

```
<form name="searchForm" novalidate style="margin-bottom: 50px">
    <div> <input ng-model="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..." name="searchTerm" required /> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

This form has a .watch to detect when the user writes some text:

```
$scope.$watch('search', function(newTerm, oldTerm) {
        filteredResponse = !newTerm ? response : updateFilteredResponse(normalize(newTerm));
        updateTree();
 }, true);
```

The function 'updateFilteredResponse' filter the nodes with label containing newTerm over original data set (read from json) and returns an array with the items to show in treeview.

The 'updateTree' function use this array and transform my custom items in the array to treeview items to add to the treeview. This items are added to 
    $scope.tree_data = [];

And this array is the one that uses abn-tree directive:

```
<abn-tree tree-data="tree_data" tree-control="my_tree" ng-if="loaded" expand-level = "2"></abn-tree>
```

This part is working fine. My problem comes when the result treeview is shown at screen, the treeview always appears completely collapsed.

If I put a button similar to the library example code like this:

```
<div style="vertical-align:top">
     <button ng-click="my_tree.expand_all()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Expand All</button>
</div>
```

And declaring this in the controller as the example:

```
var tree;
$scope.my_tree = tree = {};
```

When the users click the button to expand all over the search results, it works fine. By I need to auto-expand the treeview after a search, and remove the expand-all-button.

For that, I'm trying to call my_tree.expand_all() in my controller. I tried different calls:

```
$scope.my_tree.expand_all();
tree.expand_all();
```

In different parts of my controller and my html (using ngIf and onload directives). Even I tried to do a 'watch' over $scope.my_tree for try to use the expand_all() function when var is prepared but I always have the same error:

```
$scope.my_tree.expand_all is not a function
```

Can anyone help me with that please?

Answer (score 1):

You can put `expand_all()` function into `setTimeout` function as below.

```
   setTimeout(function() {            
        $scope.my_tree.expand_all();
        $scope.$digest();
   }, 0);
```

It have to do because it take some delay time while binding data to treeview.